# Scala Elasticsearch query with multiple parameters

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I need to delete certain entries from an Elasticsearch table. I cannot find any hints in the documentation. I'm also an Elasticsearch noob. The to be deleted rows will be identified by its `type` and an `owner_id`. Is it possible to call `deleteByQuery` with multiple parameters? Or any alternatives to reach the same?

I'm using this library: https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s

How the table looks like:

```
| id |  type | owner_id | cost |
|------------------------------|
| 1  | house |    1     | 10   |
| 2  | hut   |    1     | 3    |
| 3  | house |    2     | 16   |
| 4  | house |    1     | 11   |
```

In the code it looks like this currently:

```
deleteByQuery(someIndex, matchQuery("type", "house"))
```

and I would need something like this:

```
deleteByQuery(someIndex, matchQuery("type", "house"), matchQuery("owner_id", 1))
```

But this won't work since deleteByQuery only accepts a single Query.

In this example it should delete the entries with id 1 and 4.

Comment: Not sure about the syntax of library you are using, but they musty be supporting the boolean query, where you can use the filter on `owner_id`:1 and then use the same query

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explaining it in JSON and rest API format, to make it more clear.

**Index Sample documents**

```
put myindex/_doc/1
{
  "type" : "house",
  "owner_id" :1
  
}

put myindex/_doc/2
{
  "type" : "hut",
  "owner_id" :1
  
}

put myindex/_doc/3
{
  "type" : "house",
  "owner_id" :2
  
}

put myindex/_doc/4
{
  "type" : "house",
  "owner_id" :1
  
}
```

**Search using the boolean query**

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "type": "house"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "owner_id": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**And query result**

```
 "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "myindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.35667494,
        "_source" : {
          "type" : "house",
          "owner_id" : 1
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "myindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "4",
        "_score" : 0.35667494,
        "_source" : {
          "type" : "house",
          "owner_id" : 1
        }
      }
    ]
```